# Replace newline into <br /> and save it to database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I found this code `replace(/\\r\\n/g, "<br />");` for replacing newlines into `<br />` after entering strings inside a textarea. But I can't find answers on how to save it on database.

My questions are:

1. For example if I enter
   "Hello
   World!!!" inside a textarea 
   Will it look like `"Hello<br />World!!!"` inside the database?? or 
   Will it look like `"Hello\nWorld!!!"` inside the database?? 
   But I tried it with `<br />` and I get what I want, so am I correct that it will look like the first one??
2. How to save it into database with `<br />` ??? 
    Your response is highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Instead replacing with <br/> ,use `nl2br($datafromDB)` when you display data

Comment: Thnanks sir but what the input will look like inside the database when the textarea contains \n?? I'm just curious coz' i cant find <br /> nor \n. Is it normal to see as it is? Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the reason I already specified, you don't want to put HTML inside the database unless you're sure it will only contain HTML.

For instance, let's say my name is `"Chris Völkel"`, if you store it as HTML in the DB, it will look like: `"Chris V&ouml;lkel"`.
The problem with this is that you can't use the name anywhere else where it won't be HTML.

For example, your client might ask you to export the DB data into a CSV file. You will end up giving the client HTML inside the CSV file - not ideal, right?

Instead, you should encode the data to HTML when you render it on the web browser:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
// ...
$stmt->bind_param($data);
```

And later on...

```
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($data));
```

Comment: Thanks for response sir. But I get this error Notice: Undefined variable: stmt in C:\xampp\htdocs\powersocial\update_group.php on line 9

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\powersocial\update_group.php on line 9

Comment: That was *an example*. Don't just copy & paste code without knowing what it does.

Comment: I replace $data to $update_con and I used $_GET[] so I replace also the $_POST[] to $_GET[].

Answer (score 4):

use

`nl2br($string)`

it will automatically enter `<br />`'s where newlines are in your code

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: No, `htmlspecialchars()` should be used when rendering the page content: storing `"£"` in the DB is possibly more useful than `"&pound;"` (think accents and using the DB data somewhere outside of the web environment).

Comment: Sorry @Christian wrong function i have edited my answer to reflect. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for response sir. In the line "echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar");" it has a "\n", It means my database should have that before displaying it?? Sorry for bad english

Comment: did you enter \n when you where typing? a text area doesnt add that by default?

Comment: That function will not replace \n to a BR if your database already has \n's in it you'll need to replace them either in the database or when they are rendered out on the page so that they can be properly re-stored in the db

Comment: nope....what I want to figure out is that, what might the database contain when hitting "ENTER" inside a textarea

Comment: If you are using nl2br it will contain <br/> without that it will not store the new line all the text will come back in one single line without breaks

Comment: But when I input texts inside my textarea with a newlines and echoing it using nl2br, the texts are not displaying as what I want it to be.